# Does conditional probability that equals zero imply the events are disjoint

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Does $P(B|A) = 0$ with $P(A) \neq 0$ mean $A \cap B = \varnothing$?
I think I already have an answer, but I'm not sure it's correct.

I would say no, because we can consider a variable $X \sim U(0,1)$, described by a continuous uniform distribution, where, for example,

$A$ is "$0.2 \leq X \leq 0.9$" and $B$ is "$X = 0.5$".

This way we have
\begin{align}
P(B) = 0,   P(A) > 0,   A \cap B = B \neq \varnothing, 
\end{align}
but $P(B | A) = P(A \cap B) / P(A) = P(B) / P(A) = 0 / P(A) = 0$.

Comment: Are you taking about events or continuous random variables? For continuous random variables *all* the pointwise probabilities equal zero.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Valikeny. From the fact that $\Pr(B\mid A) = \Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(A)$ when $\Pr(A)\ne 0$ you can immediately deduce $\Pr(A\cap B)=0,$ *but you cannot conclude that any set with zero probability must be empty.*  That is not implied by the probability axioms and there exist many counterexamples.

Comment: Thank you, @whuber. So I would say the situation I described is an example of when P(A ∩ B) is 0, but the intersection itself is not empty. Am I correct? 

Tim, I am talking about events, but in my example these events are related to values assumed by a continuous random variable.

Comment: Yes, that's correct -- and it's such a common situation that we cannot easily dismiss it as being some mathematical curiosity.